# Unable to access Hadoop CLI after enabling Kerberos

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, mit-kerberos

I've followed the following tutorial [CDH Hadoop Kerberos](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cdh_sg_kerberos_prin_keytab_deploy.html#topic_3_4), NameNode and DataNode are able to start properly and I'm able to see all the DataNode listed on the WebUI (0.0.0.0:50070). But I'm unable to access the Hadoop CLI. I've followed this tutorial [Certain Java versions cannot read credentials cache](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/sg_kerberos_troubleshoot.html#legacy_java_issue), still I'm unable to use the Hadoop CLI.

```
[root@local9 hduser]# hadoop fs -ls /
20/11/03 12:24:32 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root (auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
20/11/03 12:24:32 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
20/11/03 12:24:32 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root (auth:KERBEROS) cause:java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
ls: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]; Host Details : local host is: "local9/192.168.2.9"; destination host is: "local9":8020;
[root@local9 hduser]# klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:0:krb_ccache_hVEAjWz
Default principal: hdfs/local9@FBSPL.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
11/03/2020 12:22:42  11/04/2020 12:22:42  krbtgt/FBSPL.COM@FBSPL.COM
        renew until 11/10/2020 12:22:12
[root@local9 hduser]# kinit -R
[root@local9 hduser]# klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:0:krb_ccache_hVEAjWz
Default principal: hdfs/local9@FBSPL.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
11/03/2020 12:24:50  11/04/2020 12:24:50  krbtgt/FBSPL.COM@FBSPL.COM
        renew until 11/10/2020 12:22:12
[root@local9 hduser]# hadoop fs -ls /
20/11/03 12:25:04 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root (auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
20/11/03 12:25:04 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
20/11/03 12:25:04 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root (auth:KERBEROS) cause:java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
ls: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]; Host Details : local host is: "local9/192.168.2.9"; destination host is: "local9":8020;
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first link says _"For Hadoop, the principals should be of the format username/**fully.qualified.domain.name**@YOUR-REALM.COM"_. `local9` is not a fully qualified domain name.

Comment: local9 is the fully qualified domain name. *hostname -f* gives local9 as the output.

Comment: No its not, https://www.lifewire.com/what-does-fqdn-mean-2625883.

Comment: I've set the hostname to local9 using hostnamectl -set-hostname and /etc/hostname to local9. Hence my fqdn is local9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue.
It's a cache credential bug in Redhat: [Red Hat Bugzilla – Bug 1029110](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1029110)
Then I found this document on Kerberos on Cloudera: [Manage krb5.conf](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_sg_s4_kerb_wizard.html#concept_irl_x5y_l4)

Finally the solution was to comment out this line from `/etc/krb5.conf`

`default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}`

I was able to access the Hadoop CLI after commenting this line.